# How do I decode a partial json string

Tags: php, string, json

I am using php to create a CSV and it is all working fine apart from a json string I am getting back from my database is incomplete, before people tell me to edit the record this is not possible as there are over 10 Million records and they could all be like that it returns a sting like

```
[{"school": {"id":"483494583", "name":"Ben Brown"}},{"names": {"id":"4535345"
```

I am inheriting this database from another developer all I want is the name but their is nothing to say the string is wrong every time or it the format is wrong.

All I am aiming to get is the name. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of database? What code are you using to fetch it from the database? and at what point does it get converted to JSON?

Comment: Aside from it being incomplete, it's also invalid JSON.

Comment: If all the returned strings are *equally wrong* using the same wrong syntax then add a temporary fix to append some extra values to your string to make it complete before you ask PHP to decode it

Comment: I am surprised, that "Ben Brown" is not within quotes in the JSON. How can this be?

Comment: @Leif `school`, `Id`, `name` ... should be quoteed as well.

Comment: That was my mistake they are in the code i have printed i'll edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to extract the something along the lines of

name:{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*

I have no doubt there is a PHP lib well documented to run regexes. The regex will need to be taylored to your exact needs